# is it possible to forward channel messages to myself using telegram bot whiteout admin promoting?

Tags: bots, telegram, message, forward

hello I want to know if I can use a bot for forwarding channel messages to myself or another group or channel and mind this that the bot is not the channel admin

Comment: you can by automating regular users. (look into telethon, pyrogram, etc..)

Comment: thanks @Tibebes.M I will work on it